# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'label')

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to implement Autocomplete using materialUI and nextJs. I encountered this error whenever I start the search.

My code is like this

client:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField"
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete"
import axios from "axios"


const getString = async (str) =>{
  try{
    // let searchableString = str.replace(/,/g, "")
    let url = "http://localhost:4000/searchpop?search=" + str;
    
    let { data } = await axios.get(url)
    return data
  } catch (error){
console.log(error); 
  }
}



export default function Home() {
  const [searchOption, setOption] = useState([]);
  searchOption.map((obj)=>{
    console.log(obj.population_mesh.cui_str);
  })
const onChangeOne = async (e) =>{
  if(e.target.value) {
    let data = await getString(e.target.value)

    setOption(data);
  }
}

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <div style={{marginTop: 50}}>
      <Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        filterOptions={(x)=> x}
        onChange={(e)=> console.log(e)}
        options= {searchOption ? searchOption.map((obj)=> obj.population_mesh.cui_str): []}
        // options = {hello}
        renderInput={(params)=>(
          <TextField
          {...params}
            label="Search String"
            onChange={(e) => onChangeOne(e)}
          />
            

        )}
      />
      </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am very new to these technologies. So please help me in resolving this issue.
I also dont understand below. here is population_mesh is the field and cui_str is is subfield in the data base which i want to print for autocomplete

```
options= {searchOption ? searchOption.map((obj)=> obj.population_mesh.cui_str): []}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you still need a resolution for this but here it is:

Add the getOptionLabel prop to Autocomplete and select which fields from your options you want to display:

```
<Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        filterOptions={(x)=> x}
        onChange={(e)=> console.log(e)}
        options= {searchOption ? searchOption.map((obj)=> obj.population_mesh.cui_str): []}

getOptionLabel={(option) => option.city + " " + option.searchName}

        // options = {hello}
        renderInput={(params)=>(
          <TextField
          {...params}
            label="Search String"
            onChange={(e) => onChangeOne(e)}
          />
            

        )}
      />
```